# using the variables from factory tu update the content

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand the logic of this factory thing. How can I use those variables, like save, drop, update. Can i use them like this ? `<a href="" ng-click="drop()">X</a>` . Or i have to write something else to success.

```
 app.factory("Inventory", function($resource){
    return $resource(
        "http://localhost/api/v1/inventory/:Id",
        {Id: "@Id"},
        {
            update: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {"update": true},
                isArray: false
            },
            save: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            create: {
                method: 'POST'
            },
            drop: {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a controller and inject the dependency on it for you to be able to use this factory.

Example:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, Inventory) {
  $scope.drop = Inventory.drop;
});
```

in your html:

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
  <a href="" ng-click="drop()">X</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: tnx for information, could you tell me how to drop it by id ? not all array.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by id? Do you want to pass a parameter into the factory function?

Comment: I have delete content1 delete content 2 forexample. When i click delete it deletes all objects content1 and content1. How can i delete it by id? so when i click to delete content1 it deletes that.